# Trigger to allow only rent a car up to 7 days Max

Tags: mysql

I want to create a trigger that will limit the time of rental of a car to 7 days. So, for example ... You can rent a car from 01/01/2019 - 06/01/2019 BUT 
you CANNOT rent a car from 01/01/2019 - 10/01/2019. 
Do I use BEFORE INSERT ? Any help is appreciated.

I'm also attaching my bookings table for some clarity.

```
insert into bookings (booking_id, booking_date, start_date, end_date, invoice_no, chauffeur_id, vehicle_id, customer_id, chauffeur_req,special_instructions) values (1, '2019/02/26', '2019/02/28', '2019/03/01', 1, 1, 1, 1, 'Yes', 'Be a bit early');
insert into bookings (booking_id, booking_date, start_date, end_date, invoice_no, chauffeur_id, vehicle_id, customer_id, chauffeur_req,special_instructions) values (2, '2019/02/28', '2019/02/28', '2019/03/03', 2, NULL, 2, 2, 'No','Please have some water');
insert into bookings (booking_id, booking_date, start_date, end_date, invoice_no, chauffeur_id, vehicle_id, customer_id, chauffeur_req,special_instructions) values (3, '2019/03/01', '2019/03/02', '2019/03/05', 3, NULL, 3, 3, 'No','Drive slow, children in the car');
insert into bookings (booking_id, booking_date, start_date, end_date, invoice_no, chauffeur_id, vehicle_id, customer_id, chauffeur_req,special_instructions) values (4, '2019/03/04', '2019/03/06', '2019/03/10', 4, 4, 4, 4, 'Yes','Please be silent while driving');
insert into bookings (booking_id, booking_date, start_date, end_date, invoice_no, chauffeur_id, vehicle_id, customer_id, chauffeur_req,special_instructions) values (5, '2019/03/08', '2019/03/09', '2019/03/13', 5, NULL, 5, 5, 'No','Need to be exactly on time');
insert into bookings (booking_id, booking_date, start_date, end_date, invoice_no, chauffeur_id, vehicle_id, customer_id, chauffeur_req,special_instructions) values (6, '2019/04/03', '2019/04/04', '2019/04/06', 6, 6, 6, 6, 'Yes','Children onboard, please drive slow');
insert into bookings (booking_id, booking_date, start_date, end_date, invoice_no, chauffeur_id, vehicle_id, customer_id, chauffeur_req,special_instructions) values (7, '2019/04/05', '2019/04/07', '2019/03/10', 7, NULL, 7, 7, 'No','Arrive 5 minutes early');
```

Comment: I would consider doing this in the front end rather than a a trigger.

Comment: I am not doing the front end of this as we won't be doing that. therefore I need to do it in the SQL. It's part of a project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could do this check in a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger, and raise an error condition to prevent the statement from preceding. For completeness, we probably want a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger as well (to prevent a row already inserted into `bookings` from being changed to be longer than a week.)

Something like this to get started:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `trg_bookings_bi` 
BEFORE INSERT ON `bookings`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF ( NEW.end_date > NEW.start_date + INTERVAL 7 DAY ) THEN
      SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
         SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'error end_date more than seven days after start_date';
   END IF;   
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. By saying 'to get started' I'd assume that it's possible to expand on this trigger?

Comment: This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'multiple triggers with the same action time and event for one table' - I already have a trigger BEFORE INSERT ON bookings. Does that affect it

Comment: You could add it to the existing trigger, just be careful about the error handling to ensure it does what you want.